# TypeError: Class constructor DatabaseError cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

[image]

I am trying to clone my node app to a new machine. I have it running on another computer locally without issue. It is also running on a server. But when I attempt to run my node app on this new machine I am getting the error above. All the code is the same. Can anyone shine some light on why I might be getting this error?

```
db.sequelize.sync({}).then(function() {

  http.createServer(app).listen(PORT, HOST,  function() {
    console.log('Server is running at http:// '+HOST+':'+PORT)
  })

}).catch(Sequelize.DatabaseError, function (err) {
  console.log(err)
})
```

The error is being triggered by the db.sequelize.sync call. I am running the same code both on my servers and another local machine without issue

Comment: Do you have the same versions of sequelize in `package.json?`

Comment: Yes, I installed all dependencies from the same package.json . I confirmed to make sure and they are both running ver. 6.3.5

Answer (score 0):

The error is  that I was seeing was because of the Sequelize variable. The actual error was because of the limitations set the MySQL 8 by default but because the Sequelize variable appears be be causing an error first. I wasnt seeing the MySQL upgrade error.